# Arabic text does not displays on first tap or takes too long time to load

Tags: android, android-studio, arabic, arabic-support

I am creating an app in which I need some Arabic text. I am passing that text from other activity everything else is ok but when I tap once other activity opens with empty textviews I have to press back and tap again to see text.

Do I need anything else for Arabic support. Please refer to images for clarification

here is my code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DuaShow.class);
    intent.putExtra("title",title);
    intent.putExtra("dua1",dua1);
    intent.putExtra("trans1",trans1);
    intent.putExtra("dua2",dua2);
    intent.putExtra("trans2",trans2);
    intent.putExtra("dua3",dua3);
    intent.putExtra("trans3",trans3);
    intent.putExtra("dua4",dua4);
    intent.putExtra("trans4",trans4);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and getting in other activity by

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    tit = bundle.getString("title");
    d1 = bundle.getString("dua1");
    d2 = bundle.getString("dua2");
    d3 = bundle.getString("dua3");
    d4 = bundle.getString("dua4");
    t1 = bundle.getString("trans1");
    t2 = bundle.getString("trans2");
    t3 = bundle.getString("trans3");
    t4 = bundle.getString("trans4");

    title.setText(tit);
    dua1.setText(d1);
    dua2.setText(d2);
    dua3.setText(d3);
    dua4.setText(d4);
    trans1.setText(t1);
    trans2.setText(t2);
    trans3.setText(t3);
    trans4.setText(t4);
    dua1.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    dua2.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    dua3.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    dua4.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    trans1.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    trans2.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    trans3.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
    trans4.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
```

on first Tap
[image: On first Tap]

On closing and again opening activity
[image]

Comment: @anyone? :::::::::